# How to teach a child to "tell" when she needs to go to the toilet?

Tags: toddler, pre-schooler, potty-training, toilet-training

My cousin's daughter is now **3.5 years** old. She still uses diapers all the time and does not tell ever that she needs to go to the toilet.

So, I wish to know how to teach a child from the beginning itself to "tell" when she needs to go to the toilet and not to sit silently and do the deeds in her pants.

How to know that the child is ready to learn this, and the way out?

Comment: Have you seen [these existing questions about potty-training](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training) and in particular [this related question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/how-can-i-potty-train-my-4-year-old-daughter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started teaching my son when he turned 2 a couple of months ago. Take her to the "pottie" say every 30min in the beginning and every time she goes praise her for that. Encouraging her will want her to go more, because being praised makes her feel good. Also put some underwear on during the day and not nappies (only when she sleep you should put nappies on), when she is wet she will feel uncomfortable and tell (that is when you show her the pottie and explain she has to go there when she wants to go... Also running the tap while she sits on the pottie also helps a lot....

Comment: `when she is wet she will feel uncomfortable and tell` I think that is a great advice. Is 2 the right age? Shouldn't we start a bit earlier?

Comment: you can start before 2 years old, it all depends on her stage of understanding... If she understands clearly when you tell her something and explain then yes it is perfect if you start earlier too. I only started at 2 as I first took him off his bottle which helps for during the night when he doesn't wear a nappy anymore (too lazy and to sit up and drink) then he rather leaves it for the morning. It is said that if she can go through her naps during the day without wetting her nappy then she is ready to be potty trained :) if she still wets during naptime then you should wait a little...

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Some kids learn this at age 1½, others at 2 or 2½... there is no specific "correct age", it's much more a question of when that particular child is ready.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I Have edited the question. Thanks.