# 5 year old only wants to poop wearing a diaper but refused to poop in toilet bowl

Tags: primary-schooler, potty-training

My daughter just turned 5 years old 2 weeks ago but until now she refused to sit on a toilet bowl to poop. She only uses the toilet to urinate and we have no problem with this. She even wakes up at night to urinate in the toilet by herself.

However, she refuses to sit on the toilet to poop. When she was 4, she promised to poop in the toilet once she turns 5 years old. Whenever we asked her when she will use the toilet to poop, she says, "When I'm 5." But until now, still no progress.

We are very frustrated and don't know what to do. I am thinking that my next course of action is to bring her to a child psychologist to unravel the reason why she refuses to poop in the toilet. When I ask her, she tells me things like "It's wrong" and "It's gross". I have no idea why she thinks/feels that pooping in a toilet is wrong or gross.

I have read a very similar [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/5095/30519) and read the suggestions as well. I do not believe my daughter has encopresis. I also can very much relate to the problem of that question's OP.

Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given her age, it might be a good idea to seek some professional help. I'm sure there are members of the community who can give you some good advice. I think there may be more background into her potty training experiences that may be useful in providing a good answer, which is why professional help would assist in getting to the root cause of the problem.  When did she start potty training? How did you try to potty train her? Has she got siblings and what ages? Have other carers been looking after her during the day, and have you spoken to them?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how this is different from the other question - other than that you think she doesn't have encopresis.  At this point, it seems as though it is a triplicate.  More detail to help us understand the distinctions would be nice.

Comment: In particular, this answer http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/3052/2876 seems as though it may fit your situation.