# When's the right time to teach a potty-trained toddler how to wipe their bottom?

Tags: toddler, potty-training

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what age can/should a child be able to clean itself after bowel movements?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/at-what-age-can-should-a-child-be-able-to-clean-itself-after-bowel-movements)

Our first is now more or less completely potty trained -- the last remaining issue is teaching him how to wipe. Currently we have him call us and we wipe for him.

Do you have any advice on how to tell when he's capable, good teaching methods, etc?

Comment: I had a very similar question - see here: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/at-what-age-can-should-a-child-be-able-to-clean-itself-after-bowel-movements